# I am getting error in scraping content through selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am scraping the title of jobs results on https://www.indeed.ae/jobs-in-dubai through selenium. i think .text is not working.
i am running the code through selenium which go to main website, enter selective keyword and then scrape all titles from result. but i am getting error, how can i solve this error

here is my code

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

Path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(Path)

driver.get("https://indeed.ae/")
print(driver.title)
search = driver.find_element_by_name("l")
search.send_keys("Dubai")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)


try:
    td = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "resultsCol"))
    )
    divs = td.find_elements_by_tag_name("div")
    for div in divs:
        header = div.find_element_by_class_name("title")
        print(header)
finally:
    driver.quit()

driver.quit()
```

and i am getting following error

```
Job Search | Indeed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/hp/Desktop/python projects/selenium-pycharm/selenium-bot.py", line 24, in <module>
    header = div.find_element_by_class_name("title")
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\python projects\selenium-pycharm\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 398, in find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\python projects\selenium-pycharm\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 659, in find_element
    {"using": by, "value": value})['value']
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\python projects\selenium-pycharm\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\python projects\selenium-pycharm\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\hp\Desktop\python projects\selenium-pycharm\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".title"}
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.116)


Process finished with exit code 1
```

thanks in advance

Comment: line number `24` is the error it says . its not able to find element with `class=title` . does that exist on the page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not find title because you get all of the div from the resultsCol. which means some div have title and some not.

Try this :

```
try:
    td = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "resultsCol"))
    )
    divs = td.find_elements_by_tag_name("div")
    #print(divs)
    for div in divs:
        try:
            header = div.find_element_by_class_name("title")
            print(header.text)
        except:
            continue
finally:
    driver.quit()

driver.quit()
```

which give title as output :

```
Receptionist
Administrative Assistant/ Document Controller
RECEPTIONIST
ADMIN OFFICER IN UAE
Data Entry Assistant (Fresh Graduate)
Receptionist
Replenishment Associate - Light Household - Hypermarket
DOCUMENT CONTROLLER
School Administrative Assistant - Dubai
ACCOUNTANT
```